# How do I resolve cannot open source file wdm.h error in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I recently installed Windows SDK 10.0.2262.2428
and the WDK of the same build number. When I try to #include <wdm.h> in both C and C++ I get the error "cannot open source file wdm.h". I have tried lookin in the Visusal Studio include directory and the header file is not there and it also is not in the x86 directory that houses the other header files from the WDK. How do I resolve this? learn.microsoft.com doesn't have any useful information or a way of downloading that specific header file

Comment: I have `wdm.h` at "D:\SDKs\WinDDK\6001.18001\inc\ddk".  Your paths will be different of course.  You an search (using the search tool) you entire hard-drive to find where it is.  Failing that, reinstalling the SDK and WDK might be an option.  I tend to prefer the enterprise WDK  (EWDK) rather than the online installer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk#download-icon-enterprise-wdk-ewdk)

Comment: Is there any update? Did you find the file in the SDK location?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I didn't. I find that the only way to make it work is to use the WDM driver project template in Visual Studio. I can't access it any other way

Comment: @thurizas I've done that but it seems the only way I can access it is to use the WDM driver template in Visual Studio. Outside of that I get no joy

Answer (score 0):

The default WDK install location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`.
And the wdm.h is in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<WDK version>\km`.

You need to add header file directory in project's properties -> C++ -> General ->  Additional Include Directories: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<WDK version>\km` (Or your custom  path when installing WDK)